# Transfer large number of large files to s3

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, put, qsub

I am transferring around 31 TB of data that consists of 4500 files, file sizes range from 69MB to 25GB, from a remote server to a s3 bucket. I am using `s4cmd put` to do this and put it in a bash script `upload.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="/path/to/*.fastq.gz"
for i in $FILES
do
    echo "$i"
    s4cmd put --sync-check -c 10 $i s3://bucket-name/directory/
done
```

Then I use `qsub` to submit the job:

```
qsub -cwd -e error.txt -o output.txt -l h_vmem=10G -l mem_free=8G -l m_mem_free=8G -pe smp 10 upload.sh
```

This is taking way too long - it took 10 hours to upload ~20 files. Can someone suggest alternatives or modifications to my command?

Thanks!

Comment: Use **GNU Parallel** and do some in parallel maybe? `parallel --eta -j 8 s4cmd put --sync-check -c 10 {} s3://bucket-name/directory/ ::: /path/to/*fastq.gz`

Comment: transferring from where? If another AWS service, maybe this is too slow, but if sending from your corporate datacenter to AWS, I would expect times in this range (as you have it single threaded). Even with GParallel, you may easily run into bandwidth constraints between your source system and AWS. (My thoughts may be out of date, so I'm interested to see responses from current users (always!)). Good luck!

Comment: How fast is your internet connection?   For that quantity of data you may find it faster to use a [Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/) though there is the shipping overhead on them.

Answer (score 2):

Your case may belong to the situation when copying the data onto physical media  and shipping it by regular mail is faster and cheaper than transferring the data over the internet. AWS supports such a "protocol" and has a special name for it - [AWS Snowball](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball).

> Snowball is a petabyte-scale data transport solution that uses secure
>   appliances to transfer large amounts of data into and out of the AWS
>   cloud. Using Snowball addresses common challenges with large-scale
>   data transfers including high network costs, long transfer times, and
>   security concerns. Transferring data with Snowball is simple, fast,
>   secure, and can be as little as one-fifth the cost of high-speed
>   Internet.
>
> With Snowball, you don’t need to write any code or purchase any
>   hardware to transfer your data. Simply create a job in the AWS
>   Management Console and a Snowball appliance will be automatically
>   shipped to you*. Once it arrives, attach the appliance to your local
>   network, download and run the Snowball client to establish a
>   connection, and then use the client to select the file directories
>   that you want to transfer to the appliance. The client will then
>   encrypt and transfer the files to the appliance at high speed. Once
>   the transfer is complete and the appliance is ready to be returned,
>   the E Ink shipping label will automatically update and you can track
>   the job status via Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS), text
>   messages, or directly in the Console.
>
> * Snowball is currently available in select regions. Your location will be verified once a job has been created in the AWS Management
>   Console.

The capacity of their smaller device is 50TB, a good fit for your case.

There is also a similar service [AWS Import/Export disk](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/disk/), where you ship your own hardware (hard drives), instead of their special device:

> To use AWS Import/Export Disk:
>
> - Prepare a portable storage device (see the [Product Details](https://aws.amazon.com/snowball/disk/details/) page for supported devices).
> - Submit a Create Job request. You’ll get a job ID with a digital signature used to authenticate your device.
> - Print out your pre-paid shipping label.
> - Securely identify and authenticate your device. For Amazon S3, place the signature file on the root directory of your device. For
>     Amazon EBS or Amazon Glacier, tape the signature barcode to the
>     exterior of the device.
> - Attach your pre-paid shipping label to the shipping container and ship your device along with its interface connectors, and power supply
>     to AWS.
>
> When your package arrives, it will be processed and securely
>   transferred to an AWS data center, where your device will be attached
>   to an AWS Import/Export station. After the data load completes, the
>   device will be returned to you.

Comment: Hi Leon. Thanks for the answer. One question though regarding pricing - I can understand that this solution could help faster transfer but can you explain how would it be cheaper than regular transfer over the internet?

Comment: Since incoming data to AWS S3 is free of charge, the cost advantage will be present only if you pay for your internet connection for traffic rather than bandwidth. For the opposite case (if you had to transfer **from** S3 rather than **to** S3) this solution will definitely be cheaper, since every outgoing TB costs ~$85, which adds up to almost $2.5K for your amount of data.

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that you can store any amount of data on S3 for free?

Comment: No, only uploading data to S3 is free of charge. Storing the data costs money: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Uploading data is not *completely* free, because of the per-request charge, although that is quite low.

Comment: Ahh, as my old boss always used to say to me *"Never under-estimate the bandwidth of a truckload of magnetic tapes."* R.I.P. Martin Shearer.